# How to get row index of a gridview row clicked by a user on it by javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview, click

How to get row index of a gridview row clicked by a user on it by javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little sample:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <input type="button" value="getIndex" onclick="getIndex(<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>);" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getIndex(index) {
        alert(index);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hi how to get row ID here:
<asp:Button ID="BtnSource" runat="server" Text="Source" class="showButton" OnClick='<%# "return SetRowValues("+Eval("ttppcid")+",this.id,"+Eval("Fair")+","+Eval("Good")+","+Eval("Mint")+","+Eval("Poor")+","+Eval("Fair")+")"%>' />

Answer (score 1):

Give every row an unique `id` with the same suffix.

As example:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_1">
            <td>
                <input  onpasteventorwhatever="related_function(event,1)">
                </input>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531666/gridview-asp-net-mouse-over-tr-find-which-row-was-clicked-on-server-side-code) will provide the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
            onclick="EditCell(event);"..............


<script type="text/javascript">
        function EditCell( e) {
            var rowIndex = e.srcElement.parentElement.sectionRowIndex;
            var cell = document.getElementById("GridView1").rows[rowIndex].cells[e.srcElement.cellIndex].innerText;
            alert(cell);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: To make your answer more useful for other, please provide some insight or explanation for context on your code. For help, see [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow.